# Convert GMT to Local Time.

Tags: android

Hi I am getting time from Server in this format : `Fri Nov 03 09:12:44 GMT+05:30 2017`

I want to convet this in format like `yyyy-MMM-dd  hh:mm a`

What I did id here,

```
if (!appPreference.getServerDateTime().isEmpty()) {

        try {

            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a");
            Date newDate = format.parse(appPreference.getServerDateTime());//2017-11-03 09:12:44

            format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd  hh:mm a");
            String date = format.format(newDate);

            dateFromUTC(newDate);

            mInitView.tv_lastEditeTime.setText(String.valueOf(dateFromUTC(newDate)));
            Log.d("time", "onCreateView: " + date);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return view;
}

public static Date dateFromUTC(Date date) {
    return new Date(date.getTime() + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getOffset(date.getTime()));
}
```

But I am getting same GMT time. Please guide me

Comment: I don't get your question. Could you please edit the post, to make the question more clear?

Comment: @tmuecksch thnxx fro quick reply. I am getting date from Server which I had mentioned. Now I want to convert that date in based on TimeZone. Suppose if user is from India then this date will be displayed at IST and if User is from another country the it will display time according to them.